# GFI outlet and light switch

Tags: kitchens

Does a GFI outlet need it's own wall box, or can I have a GFI and a light switch, both with separate incoming lines and outgoing loads, in the same wall box?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both circuits in the same box, as long as they're not from different systems, and there isn't more than a 300 volt difference between the circiuts. Even then, I think you just need a divider.

You'll also have to consider box fill, but that's typically not a problem.

Just make sure you keep the neutrals for each circuit separated.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading into this too much, but when you say "not from different systems", you're speaking of different lines of power, correct?  That is what I was looking to do.  I have an existing light switch in a single gang box.  I was planning to change to a double gang box and add a GFCI outlet beside the light switch.  The switch has power  coming in at top and two lines going out - one to the light fixture and one to a separate light switch on the opposite wall.  I was hoping I didn't have to change the existing light switch lines and bring in separate power to the GFCI outlet.

Comment: @Tom "different system" means different electrical source, not different branch circuits from the same source.